# What is the proper way of only having one page with get requests php?

Tags: php, mysql, get

For instance, I have viewpost.php and it's set up as needed and I only need to change the content within divs in there.

For example, I'm going to have to do viewpost.php?id=1,2,3 etc. But should I do EVERYTHING off index.php using index.php?action=viewpost&id=1?

Then also, do I use if statements, or do I communicate with my database using those get requests?

Overall, I plan to use modrewrite anyway, but I am clueless on the proper way to set up loading multiple pages off one, or a few php files.

I have a template and I just need to fill it using database data.

Comment: Search the web and SO for 'PHP single point of entry' and you'll find a lot of information about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is something very basic like this (Not very secure though)

```
$page = $_GET["action"];
if($page == null)
{
        $page = "main";
}

if (file_exists("content/$page.php"))
{
        include ("content/$page.php");
}
else
{
        include ("includes/404.php");
}
```

A better solution is to use something like http://www.smarty.net/ to handle templating and content loading. Slightly more complicated, but most likely worth the extra effort if you're doing anything beyond a very simple website.

Comment: That's all good until somebody passes in `../../../../etc/passwd%00`.

Comment: Well obviously it needs some extra security, but it's a very simple base system to get started on. I should probably have noted that though.

Comment: @user1973551: No, they have a template that gets filled with data from a database.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to be doing here, but neither of these answers answer that!

Comment: You put the code that loads the content from the database in the content/$page.php. You would have content/article.php and it would load the content from the database and format it and display it on the page.

With a template system like SMARTY, it's a bit more complicated, but the same principle applies. You have the content loading stored in separate files and load the generated content into the template.

I haven't used PHP in a long time but I used to use SMARTY and load the content file (content/$page.php), have it generate the content, load up a smarty template and inject the content.

Comment: The template file was specified by content page.

This all depends on what you're trying to do. This isn't the best way, but it will work for a basic personal website, but for anything beyond that you're going to want something more advanced.

Comment: I've been working on getting smarty to work, but I'm clueless

Answer (score 0):

index.php?action=viewpost&id=1 this code in index:

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && isset($_GET['id']))
{
$id = $_GET['id'];
if($action == "viewpost")
{
// action is viewpost
if(!ctype_digit($id))
{
// id isnt digit
die();
}
else
{
// viewpost 
include('viewpost.php');
}
}
```

**viewpost.php could look like:**
 just to be sure nothing bad happens when going right to viewpost.php you could see in the url if viewpost.php exists, or just do the security here (!ctype_digit($_GET['id']))

```
  // since its already been secured with !ctype_digit, we can run queries right away
$q_findPost = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=$id");
$r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q_findPost);
// div stuff
```

Comment: Parametrize your queries anyways.

Comment: Would this be the average website way of doing this?